# No internet connection after update from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, dns, internet

Is there anyone who may help me with the following problem? I upgraded ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 and I have problem with the internet connection. Secifically, DNS after update stopped working, I added the DNS 8.8.8.8 to configuration, but resolving is still doesn't work; The outputs of nmcli device show wlan1 | grep IP4 is:

```
pc@pc:~$ nmcli device show wlan1 | grep IP4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]: 192.168.1.3/24
IP4.GATEWAY: 192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]: dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]: 8.8.8.8
```

The output from  dig @8.8.8.8 google.com and dig google.com:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60075
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 12, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.245
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.230
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.216
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.238
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.224
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.223
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.237
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.210
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.217
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.231
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.244
google.com.     27  IN  A   62.75.23.251

;; Query time: 89 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 30 19:39:24 EEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 231
pc@pc:~$ dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

pc@pc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan1
```